# Need to close a q-popup-proxy with a button click from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have this q-popup-proxy

```
<q-btn label="Add Fault" class="addFaultButton" dense @click="openPopUp()">
  <q-popup-proxy position="center" v-if="openFaults">
    <FaultListPicker />
  </q-popup-proxy>
</q-btn>
```

with this in the setup

```
    let openFaults = computed(() => store.closeFaultPopup);
    function openPopUp() {
      store.closeFaultPopup = true;
      console.log('st ', store.closeFaultPopup)
    }
```

and this for the cancel button in the component the popup displays

```
    function Cancel() {
      console.log('cancel');
      store.closeFaultPopup = false;
    }
```

It almost works. I have to click the open button twice to get it to open. Upon the first click I see the console log and it says its true. The cancel button works - when I click cancel it goes away. How can I get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: the closeFaultPopup should be named open probably lol

Answer (score -1):

I changed v-if to v-model and it works